# Angular JS changing scope within a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a controller that handles the clicks of a buttons on a nav bar, and am trying to figure out how to change the value of '$scope.active' on each click.   I have my old code at the bottom that currently works, the value for setTab and checkTab are both passed using ng-click:

```
<a ng-click="UserCtrl.vipList(); panel.selectTab('vip')"> <li ng-class="{'selected-box': active == 'vip'}"  ng-class="{ select: panel.isSelected('vip') }"> ... etc
```

New code that does not set $scope.active. I have tried setting this value in all functions.

```
var PanelController = function($scope){
    var _this = this;
    _this.tab = 'daily';

    $scope.active = 'daily';

    $scope.selectTab = function(setTab){
     _this.selectTab();
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function(checkTab){
     _this.isSelected();
    };

};

PanelController.prototype.selectTab = function(setTab){
  this.tab = setTab;
};

PanelController.prototype.isSelected = function(checkTab){
  return this.tab === checkTab;
};

PanelController.$inject = ['$scope'];

app.controller('PanelController', PanelController);
```

Old working code that has been refactored:

```
app.factory('Panel', function(){

  var tab = 'daily';

  var setTab = function(setTab){
    return setTab;
  }

  return {
    tab: tab,
    setTab: setTab
  }

})

app.controller('PanelController', function($scope, Panel){
    this.tab = Panel.tab;
    $scope.active = 'daily';

    this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
      this.tab = Panel.setTab(setTab);
      $scope.active = this.tab;
    };

    this.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
      return this.tab === checkTab;
    };
})
```

Comment: `this` and `$scope` is the same think inside controller

Comment: I'm assuming somewhere in code you have not included that you are defining your controller with  "...as panel" such that panel.selectTab() exists and will actually be called.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$scope.isSelected = function(checkTab){
     _this.isSelected();
};
```

by

```
$scope.isSelected = function(checkTab){
     return _this.isSelected();
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to work. In order to change the value of $scope.active in the bottom code, the selectTab function works, however, in the new, top code, it does not.